# I have install rspec-rails gem ruby and rail when i run this error comming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have install rspec-rails like this and create a file static_pages_spec.rb

```
 gem list
  272  rails g rspec:install
  274  rails generate integrateion_test static_pages
```

after this i have write down this code in static_pages_soec,rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do

  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the content 'sample app'" do
        visit '/static_pages/home'
        page.should have content('Sample App')      
    end
  end
end
```

after that run this command but getting error

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:~/rails_project$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static pages spec.rb

/home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec
/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/jaskaran/rails_project/pages (LoadError)
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in your code.

```
page.should have content('Sample App')
```

should be

```
page.should have_content('Sample App')
```

If you are ever in doubt with Mike Hartl's tutorial you can always check the complete version [here](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4)

Comment: this is also true, but it doesn't solve the immediate problem the asker is having.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're running is incorrect.

You made a file called `static_pages_spec.rb` (at least I hope you did - your question is riddled with typos) but your command is looking for `static pages spec.rb`

Fix the command by adding the underscores.